# Need remoting in SQL CLR

Tags: sql-server, remoting, sqlclr

I have to process BLOBs with an external service, that's available thru remoting only (!).

So, I have to register an assembly with a reference to System.Runtime.Remoting.dll. So, I have to register this dll itself. I'd prefer to use the last framework, but at least 2.0 is enough.

When I try

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.Runtime.Remoting]
FROM  'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO
```

it says:

> CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly
>   'System.Runtime.Remoting' failed
>   because assembly
>   'System.Runtime.Remoting' failed
>   verification. Check if the referenced
>   assemblies are up-to-date and trusted
>   (for external_access or unsafe) to
>   execute in the database. CLR Verifier
>   error messages if any will follow this
>   message

When I try:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.Runtime.Remoting]
FROM  'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO
```

it says:

> Msg 10300, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Assembly 'System.Web' references
>   assembly 'system.enterpriseservices,
>   version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral,
>   publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.',
>   which is not present in the current
>   database. SQL Server attempted to
>   locate and automatically load the
>   referenced assembly from the same
>   location where referring assembly came
>   from, but that operation has failed
>   (reason: version, culture or public
>   key mismatch). Please load the
>   referenced assembly into the current
>   database and retry your request.

How should I fix this?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it. Don't process your BLOBs from inside SQLCLR if it needs to use Remoting (or Web services, or external file access). Process your BLOBs from an external application that load the BLOB, connects to the processing (using remoting or anything similat) and then updates the database.